# Typo3: How to read from database to produce UL for view

Tags: mysql, typo3

OK, in good old fashioned PHP MVC, I might use a model to hit the DB, send info to my PHP controller that I pass on to the View. In the View, I might take that info (say i ajax'ed my controller for the info) and create a `table` or `ul` to display the data returned.

I've had trouble finding any modern (ver 6.1 is what i'm on) tutorial to show me how to preform this action in typo3.

Can anyone just "steer" me in the right direction? Perhaps provide an example via answer, or some links to further information that may compare it down to "old fashioned MVC"?

Extension has been suggested, but I'd like to know the very base process of what I'm asking before I try writing some extension, unless the extension is the only way. Although, my table is now on the SAME DB my typo3 is on, so shouldn't there be some command to just simply call my table and get the rows? Maybe send them to a ###sub-part###?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... what don't you understand about the backend layout that it gives you a headache?

Comment: @cascaval As I metnioned, (maybe I'm "too" ol' school) I'm used to straight php MVC. I've used things like Codeigniter as a "foundation" but I've never used anything as convoluted as this, except maybe Sharepoint (bleh!). It "appears" very "in order" and organizational, but it took me forever to figure out "where" to place and edit template files, I still don't know where I can do any PHP work (which would be way easier) and it seems to me all the tabs and menus are just shortcuts to what I've come to learn how to do in typo3 code on the template editing area. It's just plain confusing.

Comment: @cascaval On top of all of that, there is NO documentation (in English) for the newer ver I'm expected to run and much of what I've tried from the old tutorials just doesn't work and makes me more confused and frustrated. I found API documentation, but half of it doesn't match up! some of it appears to be "php" coding references, but where in the world do you edit any php in this thing? a good portion of typo3 script I've found, seems to work, but I find nothing on reading a db table and putting the data on a "view", or as they call it, a template. Where is startup tut for MVC coders like me?

Comment: try [extension builder](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) to get basic clue of what you can do. Your emotional post doesn't give me any information of, what you're dealing with: plugin's flexform, record editing or completely new BE module, so make more focus here. And, please, don't blame TYPO3 - it is not an easy one-day-to-learn system. If you "can code in several languages", it still doesn't mean, that you're able to understand new systems fast.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: I thought you are unhappy about the backend GUI. If what confuses you is only "Where do I edit PHP?" then the answer is: Most of the time you don't because basic stuff like templating and loading of records from the database can be done using TypoScript only.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: For advanced stuff when you really need PHP coding you... 1) Write your own class with methods that you call from within the TypoScript (used for small things only). See **[includeLibs](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html)**. 2) Write your own **[extension](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/Index.html)**.

Comment: @SpYk3HH: As you mentioned that you have a need for your own database table then you should go for the 2nd option - that is writing your own extension.

Comment: @cascaval TY very much. Sorry for the emotion, but it's very frustrating not understanding something that "looks" easy to understand. I'll look into your suggestions. Could you maybe provide an example answer?

Comment: @SpYk3HH: Your question is too broad to come up with a good answer. That's why I'm sticking to comments. Come up with another question concentrating on one specific problem, describing in detail what you are trying to achieve and leave out the emotions even though I understand your frustration and admit that the documentation is not great.

Comment: @cascaval I've been reading the extension link you sent me, though i'm still quite lost on that. I simplified my question down ALOT to a very base question. Think you might could help me get started there? (note i'm not asking about doing it through an extension)

Comment: Your main problem apparently is that you take programmer's approach. Remember, Typoscript is NOT a programming language. It is intended for web developers to build websites without actually programming. Start thinking as a programmer once you get into creating your own extension, not before.

Comment: @cascaval you are right and i'm realizing that, it just makes it harder for me. tho i am trudging through it. I've pretty much answered this question, now it's extended into other problems, lol. thank you again for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a typoscript cObj content and the select option together with the function render_obj when your table name is like the typo3 nameing convention. The select pulls the record from the table and pass it to the render_obj function. It's a function that can apply to all cObj and iterate over the entire selection. stdWrap works only on the entire cObj. When you need to work through each record you need the render_obj function. For example:

```
10 = CONTENT
10 {
     select {
       pidInList = 1
       where = colpos=1
       orderBy = sorting
     }
     table = tt_content
     renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = <li>|</li>  
     renderObj.stdWrap.required = 1
 }
 10.stdWrap.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
```

This gives you an unorderd list from the tt_content table with pid=1 and the content from the far left column.

Comment: although i did pick up on this line `# The table is read from (the only approved tables are "pages" or tables prefixed with "tt_", "tx_", "ttx_", "fe_" or "user_") `. Is there a way to change this? So I can access a table I put on that same db?

Comment: FYI, I didn't down-vote this, but I will upvote for now and get it back to 0 at least. Thanks for your help thus far. I opened it in Chrome and translated. It seems somewhat helpful, though I'm still testing. Again, thank you.

Comment: another example would be great. What's confusing to me is the whole setup. Probably because I've been coding normal MVC for years now. When I want to get info from a database, I make a model PHP file to do so. When I want a Controller to work with a user end view, I make a Controller PHP file. When I want a view, I write an HTML PHP file. I manually move these files to desired locations and repeat as necessary. I don't get how Typo3 preforms. I don't understand how to do these simple task that are similar even in ASP.Net. Even Sharepoint is less complicated, it seems.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just not getting the whole picture. I've read several starter tuts, a ton of documentation and API, and watched a dozen videos, and it still just doesn't make since to me. I really wish there was a good ver6+ [English] tutorial that would walk me from begining to end on how to make a full website, using a database , having dynamic parts, and having more than one "template". But I can't seem to find anything like that.

Comment: boring or not, if they want more people to use it, they should really do a full starter tutorial. I really don't even know how my boss ended up on this. But it's not being used for our company, its for a "side-project". Making any starter tutorial, from a pro's place in life, is going to be boring, but look at EVERYTHING else out there. They all have startup tutorials; PHP MVC, ASP.Net, SharePoint, Codeigniter, CakePHP, jQuery, JavaScript, Java, Flash, Photoshop, CorelDraw. Everything has a good startup tutorial, and the big names keep them up to date. Just a fact, lol.

Comment: Oh and I get that it is a big array, I'm actually editing the "typo3" script on the template of the page i want to edit just fine. It just took me 2 weeks to figure out how to include that specific template and where in the backend to place said "script" in order to manipulate the page. That's what is frustrating. Many docs and answers say "do this", but they don't tell you "where". And most of the docs say to click on tabs that don't exist in my version, then I look, and the doc is from 2 versions ago!

Comment: FYI, My answer to my question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743344/typo3-sub-page-template-not-loading/16971631#16971631) is how I got my media page the way I want. I'm having trouble following the examples from you and the link to read the db tables and fill in the content sub-part `###typocontent###`. Could you maybe give me some pointers, and criticism if it helps me understand?

Comment: I guess what i'm asking is, how can I apply `renderObj` as seen in the link you gave, to the code I have? As metnioned, my code is shown in the ANSWER at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743344/typo3-sub-page-template-not-loading/16971631#16971631

Comment: Definatly getting closer, thank you. I'm sure I 'll figure this out eventually, for now I'll give you check mark. Thank you.

Comment: "Template" records are what you use to configure TYPO3 to make the output that you want. It is the setup part of these records where most of the configuration happens.